# Incorrect Touch Event Offsets for Scrolled Page in iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

We have a web page that contains a few div/canvas tags allowing the user to draw:

```
 <div id="Drawing" class="FormField" style="position: absolute; top: 444px; left: 121px;
      width: 302px; height: 185px; font-size: 10pt;">
      <canvas id="DrawingCanvas" class="InkFormField" width="302" height="185" style=""></canvas>
 </div>
 <div id="Picture" class="FormField" style="position: absolute; top: 915px; left: 121px;
      width: 302px; height: 167px; font-size: 10pt;">
      <canvas id="PictureCanvas" class="InkFormField" width="302" height="167" style=""></canvas>
 </div>
```

The second div/canvas (with top: 915px) is initially not visible but can be scrolled to and inked on.

The drawing is pretty straight-forward **code which works correctly for desktop browsers** (using the appropriate mouse events). For the iPad we need to use touch events to determine the point locations to draw:

```
        var touchX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX - canvasLeft;
        var touchY = e.changedTouches[0].screenY - canvasTop;
```

(where canvasLeft and canvasTop are the page-relative offsets of the canvas).

Everything works correctly, even after scrolling to the second div/canvas.

However, **once an outer  is added** to the above code (with **overflow: auto**) the touchX and touchY **values are no longer correct after the div is scrolled**:

```
  <div style="overflow: auto">
     <div id="Drawing" class="FormField" style="position: absolute; top: 444px; left: 121px;
          width: 302px; height: 185px; font-size: 10pt;">
          <canvas id="DrawingCanvas" class="InkFormField" width="302" height="185" style=""></canvas>
     </div>
     <div id="Picture" class="FormField" style="position: absolute; top: 915px; left: 121px;
          width: 302px; height: 167px; font-size: 10pt;">
          <canvas id="PictureCanvas" class="InkFormField" width="302" height="167" style=""></canvas>
     </div>
  </div>
```

As a matter of fact they seem to be off by exactly the scrolled amount! According to the documentation, the screenY property should take scrolling into account (but maybe it is referring to the page scrolling, not the outer div scrolling).

Is there a different property of the touch event that **reports the x and y offsets relative to the scrolled div** so that points can be drawn correctly?

Alternatively, is there **a way to keep track of the amount of scrolling** so an appropriate offset can be applied to the computation of touchX and touchY?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my mouse/touch code. Give it a try. It should work for you:

With touch events you can do something like:'

```
if (e.targetTouches) e = e.targetTouches[0];
```

before you call it.

```
function getMouse(e, canvas) {
  var element = canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, mx, my;

  // Compute the total offset
  if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
    do {
      offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
      offsetY += element.offsetTop;
    } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
  }

  // Add padding and border style widths to offset
  // Also add the <html> offsets in case there's a position:fixed bar
  offsetX += _stylePaddingLeft + _styleBorderLeft + _htmlLeft;
  offsetY += _stylePaddingTop + _styleBorderTop + _htmlTop;

  mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
  my = e.pageY - offsetY;

  return {x: mx, y: my};
}
```

Those offsets are as following, assuming your canvas is called "canvas":

```
_stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10)      || 0;
_stylePaddingTop  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10)       || 0;
_styleBorderLeft  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10)  || 0;
_styleBorderTop   = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10)   || 0;
// <html> can have a margin (typically seen with position:fixed bars)
var html = document.body.parentNode;
_htmlTop = html.offsetTop;
_htmlLeft = html.offsetLeft;
```

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I figured out that I can simply use the scrollTop() and scrollLeft() jQuery methods to get the amount of scrolling for the outer <div>.